# Work around on READ_PHONE_STATE and SEND_SMS

Tags: android, sms, android-manifest, android-permissions

I have an app on the Playstore that was a request from my little user community that's a must have.
My app reads blood glucose values from a site and forwards them to other phones running the same app. Some users wanted to have phone/sms ability, so they could warn/call others when their glucose readings go too low.

Well, I got the letter from Google saying that's a no-no, I applied for the exception, was declined, so I'm re-working the app. It looks like they read the manifest for these permissions.

My question is this: If a user goes and puts those permissions in manually via settings, I'm guessing I should be able to query those permissions and activate those features ? Would I be able to send SMS or activate a call without having them in the manifest but having them granted via permission settings ?

Thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would I be able to send SMS or activate a call without having them in the manifest but having them granted via permission settings ?

No, sorry. Android 6.0+ runtime permissions — including `READ_PHONE_STATE` and `SEND_SMS` — require both:

- You to request them in the manifest, and
- For the user to grant them at runtime

> Some users wanted to have phone/sms ability, so they could warn/call others when their glucose readings go too low.

`ACTION_DIAL` can be used to make it simpler to place a phone call, and `ACTION_SEND` can be used to make it simpler to send an SMS. Neither require a `dangerous` permission. Neither are completely automated, though.

Beyond that, you would be needing to look at services like Twilio, to have them place phone calls or send SMS on your behalf.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and answer.. Appreciate it.  Only other option is for users who really want it is to side load. *sigh*.. Seems like a whole bunch of developers and users are upset with this.. Again.. Thanks!!

Comment: @MichaelLiVolsi: "Only other option is for users who really want it is to side load" -- there's also F-Droid, if the app is open source.